# Binding Failure with MahAppsMetro ProgressIndicator

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, mahapps.metro

I have to following `ProgressIndicator`

```
<MahAppsControls:ProgressIndicator Width="100"
                                   Height="10"
                                   VerticalAlignment="Center"
                                   ProgressColour="White" 
                                   Visibility="{Binding ProgressVisibility}"/>
```

and in the ViewModel ascociated with this View I implement

```
private Visibility progressVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
public Visibility ProgressVisibility
{
    get { return progressVisibility; }
    set
    {
        if (value == progressVisibility)
            return;
        progressVisibility = value;
        this.OnPropertyChanged("ProgressVisibility");
    }
}
```

The problem is this binding is failing and I don't know why. Using Snoop I have the following

> System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ProgressVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator')'. BindingExpression:Path=ProgressVisibility; DataItem='ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator');
>
> target element is 'ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ProgressVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator')'. BindingExpression:Path=ProgressVisibility; DataItem='ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator');
>
> target element is 'ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')
>   System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'ProgressVisibility' property not found on 'object' ''ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator')'. BindingExpression:Path=ProgressVisibility; DataItem='ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator');
>
> target element is 'ProgressIndicator' (Name='progressIndicator'); target property is 'Visibility' (type 'Visibility')

I appreciate that there is a binding error, but I am setting the main window's `DataContext` in the App.xaml.cs via

```
MainWindow window = new MainWindow();
MainWindowViewModel mainWindowViewModel = new MainWindowViewModel();

// When the ViewModel asks to be closed, close the window.
EventHandler handler = null;
handler = delegate
{
    mainWindowViewModel.RequestClose -= handler;
    window.Close();
};
mainWindowViewModel.RequestClose += handler;

// Allow all controls in the window to bind to the ViewModel by setting the 
// DataContext, which propagates down the element tree.
window.DataContext = mainWindowViewModel;
window.Show();
```

So, **Why is the binding failing?**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: That's a nasty one - you're not doing anything wrong, it's a "bug" in how MahApps is built :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is a bug in the `MahApps.ProgressIndicator` control.

If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/MahApps/MahApps.Metro/blob/master/MahApps.Metro/Controls/ProgressIndicator.xaml.cs), you'll notice that it overwrites the `DataContext` to itself:

```
public ProgressIndicator()
{
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = this;
```

As such, you'll need to work around this (stupid) limitation by binding to an element name directly, effectively avoiding using the normal data binding.

For example, if you name your `Window` (in the xaml), ie:

```
<Window ...
    Name="Self">
    <!--...
```

You could do:

```
<MahAppsControls:ProgressIndicator Width="100"
                               Height="10"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center"
                               ProgressColour="White" 
                               Visibility="{Binding ElementName=Self, Path=DataContext.ProgressVisibility}"/>
```

Comment: Damn your cool. Did not think that this could be a MahApp bug. Stupid my me. Thanks very much for your time Reed, it is much appreciated...

Comment: How did you know to look at the source? Do you use the MahApps library?

Comment: @Killercam No - just a guess, since your xaml/code looked right, but it's using an open source lib, which isn't always top quality ;)

Comment: Well, I thank you very much. I am learning MVVM/WPF on my own time with a new application and I am struggling every bit of the way [to be totally honest]!

Comment: @Killercam I've gotten good feedback from http://reedcopsey.com/series/windows-forms-to-mvvm/  (If you're interested)

Comment: Oh great. Massive thanks - people like yourself are what make this site great. Have a good day bud...